# Equivalent of ObjectOutputStream, saving not only its state but the whole object?

Tags: java, serialization, classloader

I'm letting the user import plugin-like classes from a remote location using URLClassLoader, so these imported classes do NOT exist in the build path (however, they all implement an interface *IPlugin* which is included).

I assumed one could simply use ObjectOutputStream to save all the loaded plugins to file, and later read these with ObjectInputStream. That doesn't seem to be the case though, since all it saves is the state of the object, not the containing logic (i.e. methods).

What I'd hope to do is to save the list of loaded plugins (activePlugins) with ObjectOutputStream:

```
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(*fileoutputstream*);
oos.writeObject(activePlugins);
oos.close();
```

Then at another runtime, load/restore all these plugins with ObjectInputStream:

```
ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(*fileinputstream*);
activePlugins = (ArrayList<IPlugin>) ois.readObject();
```

But since the actual object classes are not available in the build path (they are somewhere else on the harddrive), it goes haywire. What I'm after is some way of loading objects without having the classes available, i.e. loading objects with states and without dependencies.

Comment: You have to serialize the class bytes on the stream as well. You can get the class bytes through `getResourceAsStream`, Then on the other side, use these bytes to load classes in a custom class loader, then cast the resultant class to your interface, and use the object through your interface.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need your own classloader.  you basically want something similar to URLClassLoader, but with the ability to download and cache the jars locally.  you might want to look at extending URLClassLoader or implementing something similar to it.  you basically need to just hook into the part where the jar is downloaded and stick it somewhere locally (or load it from that cached location if you already downloaded it previously).

Comment: I've been looking at the question for a couple of minutes. I couldn't understand the problem at first since he's both talking about state and methods. I think it sounds like he actually both want to have a custom classloader (NetworkClassLoader) and ObjectOutputStream. Sounds like he wants to save the sate of the plugins, and not only the plugins. Or am I totally off the map now?

Comment: good point, i missed that he actually _did_ want the object states saved as well.  updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at RMI. This extends serialization with a class transferring mechanism, so you can serialize and deserialize objects of (at the receiver) unknown classes at well, and execute their methods.

This is done using some remote class loading mechanism, I think.

Comment: Using RMI just for the sake of loading classes sounds wrong. He doesn't want to execute remote methods as far as I have understood it.

Comment: RMI uses the annotation facility of Java Serialisation to link to the URL of the code (although it can be switched off).

Answer (score 0):

Altought Java is not my primary programming framework, I have seen the same problem in other "frameworks" like PHP, Delphi and C#.

One solution is to have declared class files & paths.

The other suggestion, is that, since you expecified, you don't care about the logic, only ("data") state, you could declare a generic class that stores the value of the properties.